# How can I cast a string to a decimal using a custom DbFunction

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a table with decimals (and other types) saved as strings. I want to write a Linq query on the database context that will translate to a database cast and not a local cast (for performance reasons).

This **non-working** example is conceptually what I want to achieve.

```
using ( var context = new MyContext() )
{
    return context.SomeTable
        .Select(o => new { o.Id, (decimal)o.SomeString });
}
```

This is a **bad way** to achieve it since it will run the conversion on the application side.

```
using ( var context = new MyContext() )
{
    return context.SomeTable
        .Select(o => new { o.Id, o.SomeString })
        .ToList()
        .Select(o => new { o.Id, Convert.ToDecimal(o.SomeString) });
}
```

I believe the way to go is with DbFunctions but I cannot find a way to use it with Code First.

This is the partial answer, but I have not been able to find the documentation I required to finalize the part where I define what this function does on the SQL server.

```
[DbFunction("MyContext", "ConvertToDecimal")]
public static decimal ConvertToDecimal(string s)
{
    throw new Exception("Direct calls are not supported.");
}
```

.

```
using ( var context = new MyContext() )
{
    return context.SomeTable
        .Select(o => new { o.Id, ConvertToDecimal(o.SomeString) });
}
```

**If I was using a Edmx** driven alternative, this would be the missing part:

```
<Function Name="ConvertToDecimal" ReturnType="Edm.Decimal">
    <Parameter Name="s" Type="Edm.String" />
    <DefiningExpression>
        CAST(s AS decimal(22,6))
    </DefiningExpression>
</Function>
```

I am using Entity Framework 6 Code First.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out the solution with some information coming from [this](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/discussions/466706) topic.

Like I was assuming in the original question, I had the first 2 parts down. The last part is to register in the DbModel the functions you want accessible and how to use them. There is more then one way to do this but I used a Convention

```
public class MyFunctionsConvetion : IStoreModelConvention<EntityContainer>
{
    public void Apply(EntityContainer item, DbModel model)
    {
        //Get the Edm Model from the DbModel
        EdmModel storeModel = model.GetStoreModel();

        //Delare your parameters name, edm type and mode (You can ignore this if you use a parameter-less function)
        List<FunctionParameter> Parameters = new List<FunctionParameter>();
        Parameters.Add(FunctionParameter.Create("StringValue", GetStorePrimitiveType(model, PrimitiveTypeKind.String), ParameterMode.In));

        //Same thing goes for the return type(s) (Why is it a list? Perhaps you can return tables? I haven't tested however since it is no use to me)
        List<FunctionParameter> ReturnParameters = new List<FunctionParameter>();
        ReturnParameters.Add(FunctionParameter.Create("ReturnValue", GetStorePrimitiveType(model, PrimitiveTypeKind.Decimal), ParameterMode.ReturnValue));

        //Create the payload and fill the required information alone with the parameter lists we declared
        EdmFunctionPayload payload = new EdmFunctionPayload();
        payload.IsComposable = true;
        payload.Schema = "dbo";
        payload.StoreFunctionName = "ConvertToDecimal";
        payload.ReturnParameters = ReturnParameters;
        payload.Parameters = Parameters;

        //Create the function with it's payload
        EdmFunction function = EdmFunction.Create("ConvertToDecimal", "MyContext", DataSpace.SSpace, payload, new MetadataProperty[] { });

        //Add it to the model
        storeModel.AddItem(function);
    }

    //Little helper method to get the primitive type based on the database provider
    private EdmType GetStorePrimitiveType(DbModel model, PrimitiveTypeKind typeKind)
    {
        return model
            .ProviderManifest
            .GetStoreType(TypeUsage.CreateDefaultTypeUsage(PrimitiveType.GetEdmPrimitiveType(typeKind)))
            .EdmType;
    }
}
```

Then we add the Convention to the model in the OnModelCreating method

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Add<MyProject.MyConventions.MyFunctionsConvention>();
```

Note: The code could be cleaner and written in a DRY fashion, but for the sake of simplicity, I wanted to post it like this and let you organize it however you see fit.

Comment: I just wanted to point out (since I received a +1 vote on the question) that this solution uses deprecated methods since EF 6.1. It's probably a quick change but since it still works like this, I do not have time to go into the details.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can not as per current version user defined functions are one of the elements that are not yet supported in code first.

Comment: Any documentation to support this statement? I heard from some forum a while ago that it was a new feature of EF6. If you can confirm your statement, I will accept this answer and move on.

Comment: @Pluc no, there simply is no documentatio nbecause it is not supported. A EF 6 new feature was SP's for insert /udpate etc. - do you have any reference to back up the claim it is a new feature? Because the specs in the documentation do not have that: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=specs

Comment: I would have linked it if I did. Like I said, it's just a vague memory that I saw it was possible since EF6. I suppose I saw this in a dream. I'll let the question run for an hour just to make sure. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Pluc at the end, sadly, EF is moving slowly. All hope seems lost ;) I wish they would move faster.... and not into useless directions like the coming Index attribute.

Comment: I just managed to do exactly what I wanted. I will post an answer in about an hour on how to do it.

Comment: Great - looking forward to it ;)

Comment: There you go. Take a look and tell me what you think!

Comment: Working. Sadly not an answer. Yes, you can manipulate the EDM Mdodel - and that is a good way to do it, but it does not use any Code FIrst API - which is a shame (they should get faster supporting that stuff). Well made ;)