# Can I call my own methods whilst instantiating objects in Linq to SQL Query?

Tags: c#, linq, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have the following query:

```
var userQuizzes = from quiz in Context.Quizzes
                  select new DashboardQuiz
                  {
                      QuizId = quiz.Id,
                      Questions = quiz.Questions
                      QuestionExcerpt = quiz.QuizVersion.Questions.FirstOrDefault().QuestionText
                      // etc...
                  }
```

That's all well and good, but is it possible to call my own methods that perform logic on the data *as the models are instantiated*?

I have a method on my `Quiz` POCO class `IsQuizActive()` that determines from the values in `Quiz` if the quiz is active.

So for example:

```
var userQuizzes = from quiz in Context.Quizzes
                  select new DashboardQuiz
                  {
                      QuizId = quiz.Id,
                      Questions = quiz.Questions
                      QuestionExcerpt = quiz.QuizVersion.Questions.FirstOrDefault().QuestionText

                      // Custom method IsQuizActive() called here
                      ActiveQuiz = quiz.IsQuizActive()
                  }
```

I get an error saying that it can't be converted to LINQ, which is understandable, but I created `DashboardQuiz` to use as my View Model.

As it currently stands, I have to loop through my objects and create another model `DashboardQuizViewModel` that can be used as a view model for each item:

```
var userQuizzes = from quiz in Context.Quizzes
                  select new DashboardQuiz
                  {
                      QuizId = quiz.Id,
                      Questions = quiz.Questions
                      QuestionExcerpt = quiz.QuizVersion.Questions.FirstOrDefault().QuestionText
                      // I'd like to call IsQuizActive() here
                  }

List<DashboardQuizViewModel> responseModel = new List<DashboardQuizViewModel();

foreach (var dashboardQuiz in userQuizzes)
{
    DashboardQuizViewModel viewModel = new DashboardQuizViewModel();
    viewModel.QuizId = dashboardQuiz .id;
    viewModel.Questions = dashboardQuiz.Questions;
    viewModel.QuestionExcerpt = dashboardQuiz.QuestionExcerpt;

    // Call it here instead
    viewModel.ActiveQuiz = dashboardQuiz.IsQuizActive();

    responseModel.Add(viewModel);
}

return responseModel;
```

The only other 'tidy' way that I can think of, is to have `IsQuizActive` as a getter on my View Model and call that from within the view.  But I really want the values to be evaluated before passing it to my view model

Comment: Yes, You can put your custom logic, but you need to write custom model defined functions for this. refer this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456845(v=vs.100).aspx  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352312/how-can-i-cast-a-string-to-a-decimal-using-a-custom-dbfunction

Comment: Cool!  The model defined function looks like the way to go?  Are there any drawbacks to the user defined functions?

Comment: i think we can use user defined functions with EDMFunctionattribute http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2008/10/08/edm-and-store-functions-exposed-in-linq.aspx.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9970181/4073386 Basically does the same thing but you can save some code writing.

Comment: Oh noo... I've just realized that the model defined functions don't work for code first, as you define them in the EDMX... there is no EDMX for code first. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done without creating a model defined function for sql as the query is converted to SQL and SQL does not recognise IsQuizActive as a function by default. You could possibly put the logic in the query but it is very untidy and inefficient. You could shorten the way you are looping through though. I think this should work (calling toList() executes the query and therefore you do not need to convert it to a different view model if you don't want to):

```
var userQuizzes = from quiz in Context.Quizzes
              select new DashboardQuiz
              {
                  QuizId = quiz.Id,
                  Questions = quiz.Questions
                  QuestionExcerpt =     quiz.QuizVersion.Questions.FirstOrDefault().QuestionText
                  // I'd like to call IsQuizActive() here
              }

var newUserQuizzes = userQuizzes.ToList().Select(x => {
    x.ActiveQuiz = x.IsQuizActive();
    return x;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the neater version of the loop.  I'll go for that for now as I can't do model defined functions in code first.